# Raspberry Pi Refusing SSH Connections?

Tags: ssh

I have this RPi that I got for Christmas and I was excited to use it, but I found out I don't have a keyboard. I was relieved when it said you could remotely access it through a local network. I'm trying to do this with my Ethernet plugged into my computer and then directly in my RPi, but it doesn't work. It worked when I plugged it into the router, but it took a lot of bandwidth which pissed my father off because he couldn't watch TV (he uses Internet TV). I port forwarded the port and turned off AVG and allowed putty as a program on my firewall but nothing helped. Any ideas?

Comment: hooking up the raspberry pi and the computer directly needs some configuration. 
Btw, are you running raspbian?

Comment: @feverDream Yes, I'm running Rasbian. Also, I've waited 30 minutes. How much longer?

Comment: I meant be patient and connect it to the router when nones using the internet. Rasbian comes with ssh enabled now, so read up on what you need to connect to it from you host machine.

Comment: @feverDream So can I not just configure it directly?

Comment: Before connecting to it you need to find out the ip-address of the pi. Are you comfortable with accessing your routers admin page?

Comment: I already know the IP.

Comment: Sweet, can you login to the device using putty?

Comment: Nope, that's the whole reason why I asked this question. It says Network Error: Connection Refused.

Comment: @feverDream I used ipconfig (while directly connected to my PC) to find the IP. Is that the right IP?

Comment: you should be a more clear with your question, you said ,"I'm trying to do this with my Ethernet plugged into my computer and then directly in my RPi, but it doesn't work. It worked when I plugged it into the router".
These are two different things.

Comment: @feverDream But how would I go along with using SSH locally without having to connect it to the router again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK there are two ways to remotely configure a raspberry pi:

1. Connecting it to your home network
2. Connecting it directly to your laptop's ethernet-port (using a crossover-cable)

The first approach is simple as raspbian comes with ssh enabled these days. So find the ip-address allocated to it by your router.

After that download putty and try to ssh to that machine and login withe the username `pi` and password `raspberry`.

The crossover-approach needs more work and more importantly access to the machine, so its ruled out in your case.

Comment: Try reading adafruits tutorial on ssh-connectivity.
http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-6-using-ssh

Comment: Ah thank you! I thought a simple CAT-5 Ethernet cable would suffice for the second option.